# M2 - Display "in stock / out of stock" ONLY when item is out of stock?

Tags: magento-2.1, out-of-stock, stock-status

I've just turned on the option "Display Products Availability in Stock on Storefront" which is working as it should - display either "in stock" or "out of stock" on the front end, but I want to change the default behavior so that the message only shows when a product is out of stock...

So "In stock" = no message and "Out of Stock" = Shows out of stock message

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit this file in your template, if the file is not exist please copy it from the original theme to your theme.

**app/design/frontend/{VendorName}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright آ© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView */?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>
<?php if( $_product->getData("not_saleable")) return; ?>
<?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if (!$_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow the below code.

Need to do changes in default.phtml file (**Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml**)

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
 <div class="stock available">
        <span>
            <?php / @escapeNotVerified / echo __('In stock') ?>
        </span>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="stock unavailable">
        <span>
             <?php / @escapeNotVerified / echo __('Out of stock') ?
        </span>
</div>
```

I hope it will help you.